# Trying to use Escape Characters in this Ruby method. No Luck

Tags: ruby

First off, I'd like to thank everyone who will read or has helped me in the past with my Ruby questions. Thank you for your help and understanding.

I'm having issues with printing my answers w quotes. when I print out for whats below, I get KB, MY and MLG w/o quotes. I've tried adding a line for escape characters to try and add quotes, but nothing happens. Even tried the %() method and %Q() with no effect. What am I missing here? Maybe I wrote my escape characters in the incorrect way to include quoutes?

Thanks a lot!

```rb
def to_initials(name)
  newName = name.split(" ").each {|c| print c.chr}.to_s
  withQuotes = "\"" + newName + "\""

  return withQuotes
end


to_initials("Kelvin Bridges")      # => "KB"
puts
to_initials("Michaela Yamamoto")   # => "MY"
puts
to_initials("Mary La Grange")      # => "MLG"
```

Comment: Hint #1: On which line do you print the name? Hint #2: On which line do you add the quotes? Hint #3: Which line comes first?

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using `Array.each` over the splitted name. This will execute the block directly, just like a `for` loop in Python/Java/C/etc. You’re calling `print c.chr` in the block so it just prints the firt character right away.

Second, you can use string interpolation to display the value of a variable inside strings. For instance:

```rb
my_var = 1
my_string = "#{my_var}"
```

Here’s how I would write your code:

```rb
def to_initials(name)
  initials = name.split(" ").map {|c| c.chr}.join
  return "\"#{initials}\""
end


kb = to_initials("Kelvin Bridges")      # => "KB"
puts kb
my = to_initials("Michaela Yamamoto")   # => "MY"
puts my
mlg = to_initials("Mary La Grange")      # => "MLG"
puts mlg
```

Comment: `name.split(" ").map {|c| c.chr}.join` could be written as `name.split(" ").map(&:chr).join`. You could also say `%Q("#{initials}")` to avoid some backslashes.